# Custom paper character sheet that's updatable without erasing

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-sheets, tool-recommendation

So far I've been using a printed copy of the official character sheet for my D&D characters.

It features a blank space for every stat. As a consequence of that, every time my character levels up I have to erase whatever number I wrote and write new ones. After a few levels, this wear and tear adds up and the character sheet becomes barely usable.

Sure, I could print a fresh character sheet every level and fill it up with the new stats. But, as you may have experienced, during a campaign the sheet gets covered with all kind of notes, and copying those all can be pretty boring and prone to error.

I'm about to start a new campaign, and I was searching for a custom printed character sheet that's easy to update. Possibly one with little dots or squares to represent the numbers, so that when I need to add 2 points to an ability, I can just mark two more dots. For that reason, it may take more pages than the standard sheet, that's fine.

I'd like a ready made solution, preferably a PDF that I can print.

Comment: Relevant: [tape trick to prevent erasing damage](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19742/321), and [this question about preventing wear-and-tear](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/369/character-sheets-paper-or-plastic).

Comment: I think the second question linked by SevenSidedDie is a good match for this question (maybe close enough for a duplicate close vote). In particular, @Numenetics answer of putting the character sheet in a copysafe plastic envelope and using a dry erase marker.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks for the tape trick, I could use it for the temporary effects and money cells where there's no other way than using the rubber. I guess it's not possible to not erase anything, yet I stand by my desire to find a conveniently updatable character sheet.

Comment: Savage World's character sheet works similarly to what you're asking, in that you fill in the dice as you level skills/attributes up.  It's not an answer to your question, but it might serve some inspiration.  https://www.peginc.com/freebies/SWcore/SWDCharacterSheet.pdf

Comment: @Toast Sounds good. Please add a link :)

Comment: I keep all of my characters on Obsidian Portal. With tablet in hand, paper went the way of the do-do.

Answer (score 7):

You could have the character sheet printed and laminated somewhere like staples for next to nothing as far as cost and use wet erase markers to update it. This is something I have found useful during campaigns.

Comment: Came here to say this.  However, you have to be careful that you don't accidentally rub the stats off!

Comment: My current group does exactly that for game scenarios. However, a character sheet would be too easy to accidentaly clear :)

Comment: You can use a plastic sleeve also.  This lets you alter things that change frequently with a dry erase marker, but keep less frequently changing stats permanently marked down.

Answer (score 4):

As for PDF-based character sheets, [Dyslexic Studeos’](http://charactersheets.minotaur.cc/) are by-far the highest-quality that I have seen. But I don’t think you’re likely to find a non-digital sheet that can be updated without an eraser.

A digital sheet, on the other hand, can have anything edited with ease, and most automatically update dependent variables based on any changes you make (increase your Dexterity, and all the Dex-based skills go up automatically).

Personally, I tend to prefer [The Tangled Web](http://thetangledweb.net/)’s 3.5 character sheets over MythWeavers’. They’re almost identical to MW’s non-alpha sheets, but small differences (like the checkboxes for extra weapons/armor you may or may not need, and using the checkbox for “class skills” rather than “cross-class skills”) make a difference for me. I have not tried MW’s new alpha 3.5 sheets, as at this point I use my own custom sheets – but those aren’t anything *like* easy-to-update (unless, like me, you are deeply familiar with the source code and what edits need to be made where...).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like a ready made, blank character sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[Mythweaver](http://www.myth-weavers.com/sheetindex.php) is a good place to start.

If online sheet-tracking is an option for you, Mythweaver covers a wide range of character sheets (including DnD 3.5e, as you've requested) and is fully editable, customizable, and easy to update.

There are other online sheet-keeping methods of course - and if you don't favor relying on a sever to host your info, you could always use a simple Doc file to track all your character data (format subject to your own preference).

Comment: Thanks but I'd like a ready made solution, like a printable pdf.

Comment: @Agostino It’s pretty easy to print out webpages.

Comment: @Zibbobz I have ink and toner to spare, what I need is the link to a specific sheet. I don't need a generator or a repository of sheets, just one blank sheet that's ready to print. It may be a webpage, but not one I need to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a laminated sheet and Mark it with a permanent marker. They won't accidently erase. In order to erase your old marks, write over them with a dry erase marker, then simply wipe clean.